# How to add the authentification information in SOAP header by using suds in Python

Tags: python, soap, suds

I have a issue when i try to connecting to a webservice, the wsdl is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions 
    xmlns:typens="urn:test" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    name="test" 
    targetNamespace="urn:test">
<message name="webservice">
<part name="method" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="data" type="soapenc:Array"/>
</message>
<message name="webserviceResponse">
<part name="webserviceReturn" type="soapenc:Array"/>
</message>
<portType name="soapWsPortType">
<operation name="webservice">
<documentation>Webservice</documentation>
<input message="typens:webservice"/>
<output message="typens:webserviceResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="soapWsBinding" type="typens:soapWsPortType">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="webservice">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:soapWsAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body namespace="ns1" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body namespace="ns1" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="testService">
<port name="soapWsPort" binding="typens:soapWsBinding">
<soap:address location="http://soapwebservice.doctorsender.com/soapserver.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

and i have been try to create the Element statement in suds but it's not work, here is my code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
from suds.sax.element import Element

imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', location='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url_doctor, doctor=doctor, cache=None)

user = 'someuser'
pwd = 'somepwd'

user_header = Element('user').setText(user)
pwd_header = Element('pass').setText(pwd)
header_list = [user_header, pwd_header]

client.set_options(soapheaders=header_list)
client.service.webservice('somemethod')
```

here is what i got:

```
(Array){
   item[] = 
      (item){
         key[] = 
            "error",
         value[] = 
            True,
      },
      (item){
         key[] = 
            "msg",
         value[] = 
            "Error: autentication failure.",
      },
 }
```

This webservice is very stranger and i even try to write a xml file manuelly but it dose not work either, so thanks in advance for any helpful information.

Comment: If you can't make it work with hand-written xml there's no way you can make it work with suds or any other SOAP lib...